# Why is Word 2019 not saving changes that I make to a bullet Style after I close my document?

Tags: microsoft-word, styles, bullets, microsoft-word-2019

I've made multiple bullet styles in Word 2019. For one of them, I want to adjust the position of the bullet slightly. According to the value for bullet position (accessed by right-clicking on the bullet), it matches my other bullet styles (like I want).

However, it is slightly off when I look at it and when I click on the First Line Indent slider on the ruler and compare it to another bullet style. I have made the adjustment with the slider and then Updated  to Match Selection. This applies the change throughout my document to that style.

However, if I close the document, whenever I re-open it, it's as if I never made that adjustment with the ruler to the bullet. What am I doing wrong? And why is the bullet slightly misaligned if its numerical value for its position is the same as my other bullets?

Comment: What file format are you saving the document in? `.doc`? `.docx`? `.rtf`?

Comment: See http://shaunakelly.com/word/bullets/controlbullets20072010.html and http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/NumberAlignment2007.htm.

Comment: @spikey_richie: .docx